# Says I need to update my sharepoint site collection

Tags: update

But can I just let it do it itself?

How long does it take etc? I'd rather not touch it at all - and make it do it itself - but can't risk it being down 24 hours on a weekday or so... no clue how long it takes?

Comment: Can you show up a screenshot of what you are looking at?